# Which method is faster than Burnside lemma?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I was trying to solve the following problem using Burnside's lemma, but when testing the solution for a $12\times 12$ matrix involving $20$ possibilities for each matrix element, it had an awful run time.

Does this problem have a better solution than the Burnside's lemma, so it can give the result with a better time complexity?

The problem:

> Suppose that a matrix is equivalent to another one if it can be obtained by swapping the rows and/or columns of the other one.  The goal is to find the number of inequivalent $h\times w$ matrices with each of its elements having $s$ possible choices.

For example,

```
1 5    
0 0
```

would be equivalent to itself and to:

```
0 0
1 5
```

and would also be equivalent to:

```
0 0 
5 1
```

and to:

```
5 1
0 0
```

Comment: what does swapping rows and columns mean?

Comment: It might be useful to consider that this swapping preserves the row sums and column sums.

Comment: This question recently appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056708/).