# Burnside's lemma exercise

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions

I have this combinatorial exercise which I think should be solved using Burnside's lemma.
I used this link as a reference to study: https://brilliant.org/wiki/burnsides-lemma/
It sounds pretty simple but I can't make it work.

I have an R×C grid in which each of the cells can take value 0 or 1.
I am asked to calculate the number of possible orbits.
Equivalency is defined as: any two grids with each cell in the same state where the actual order of the rows and columns do not matter (and can thus be freely swapped around).

An orbit is defined as the set of equivalent grids.

Having said that, I'm trying to start with a simple grid, a 2x2.
Ignoring Burnside for the moment, and taking all the combinations, I get 2^4 = 16 grids.
I wrote the 16 possibilities and I could see that from these I get 7 orbits.

Burnside say that the number of Orbits equals the sum of Fixed Points divided by the number of Symmetries (transformations) of the grid.
I wish I could get 7 orbits by applying Burnside to the 2x2 grid but I can't figure out.

In fact at the moment I found 3 possible Symmetries, based on the equivalency provided by the text

- The identity, for which I do not apply any transformation
- Exchange of columns
- Exchange of rows

For each of these I also check the number of fixed points by hand:

- Identity -> 16
- Column -> 4
- Row -> 4

I apply Burnside: Orb = (16 + 4 + 4) / 3 = 8 while it should be 7.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing the action "swap row and swap column". Check that this gives you $(16 + 4 + 4 + 4) / 4 = 7$. (I did not carefully verify it myself.)

Comment: How can "swap row and swap column" be considered a valid action if it is made by two of the other actions?

Comment: Groups are closed under the group operation. For permutation groups, the operation is function composition. So not only does a permutation $\pi$ being a composition $\pi=\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2$ of two group elements $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ not only *not* invalidate $\pi$ being an element of the group $G$, but it actually *implies* the composition $\pi$ *must* also be an element of $G$! Because groups are closed under their operation!

Comment: Some related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113657/burnsides-lemma-applied-to-grids-with-interchanging-rows-and-columns https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056708/number-of-equivalence-classes-of-w-times-h-matrices-under-switching-rows-and

Comment: Ok, i did understand and I figured out what I was missing in the 2x2 grid, but I can't figure out other cases. For example if the grid is a simple 3x1, how many symmetries are there?

Comment: Just to piggyback on the above comments. The group of actions that govern the rule "order of the rows and columns do not matter (and can thus be freely swapped around)" is the product of two symmetric groups (symmetric group is the group of all permutations) $S_R \times S_C$. In this case we have $S_2 \times S_2$ which is also called the Klein four-group.

Comment: The $R \times C$ has $R!C!$ symmetries: permute the rows in any of $R!$ ways and permute the columns in any of $C!$ ways.

Comment: Thank's Austin Mohr, those question could be very helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of equivalence classes of $w \times h$ matrices under switching rows and columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056708/number-of-equivalence-classes-of-w-times-h-matrices-under-switching-rows-and)