# Compute the number of unique, non-equivalent configurations of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

Consider a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$. Each element of this matrix, denoted here as $a_{ij}$, is a non-negative integer from $0$ to $s$, i.e. $a_{ij}\in\{0,1,2,...,s\}$. The problem is to compute the number of unique, non-equivalent configurations of $\mathbf{A}$. Equivalency is defined as: for a given configuration of $\mathbf{A}$, if by swapping any two rows or columns a given number of times we arrive at some other configuration, then these two configurations are equivalent. For example, considering $m=n=s=2$, the following matrices:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
are all equivalent since:

- From the first matrix we can obtain the second by swapping the columns.
- From the first matrix we can obtain the third by swapping the rows.
- From the first matrix we can obtain the fourth by swapping the rows and columns.

Again, the objective is to compute the number of unique, non-equivalent configurations of $\mathbf{A}$ considering the general parameters $m$, $n$, and $s$.

---

My background is mechanical engineering and I've never formally studied combinatorics, so, any help is greatly appreciated and I apologize for my naiveness.

Comment: For the square case, see [OEIS A002724](https://oeis.org/A002724), [OEIS A246106](https://oeis.org/A246106). Look also at the related cross references. For specific cases, you could try to use genbg, at least for binary matrices, like in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/401657/136218).

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2835508/122921) along with code to compute `count(m,n,s)` as `answer(n,m,s)` (though the order of the size parameters does not matter). For `answer(2,2,2)` the result is 7; the rows of each matrix are shown below:

```
([0, 0], [0, 0])
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
[[0, 1], [1, 1]]
([1, 1], [1, 1])
```

Note: the code I reference does not compute the matrices, only counts them. I have code [at this SymPy page](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23342) that will enumerate the matrices for a given set of elements -- see `umat` on that page.